# Seemingly random file corruption during FileOutputStream saving

Tags: java, io, fileoutputstream

I have a Java Android app that routinely saves user data. It's usually a lot of data, and can take a few minutes to save. However, it's been deployed like this for a long time and works well.

Randomly, however, a file becomes corrupt. Upon very meticulous debugging output when opening the files, I can poinpoint the exact place in the reading of the data that the first inconsistency is found.

```
// This is just a small section of the data being read. I'm outputting it as it's coming in. This data is in no special position in the middle of the file
// (The file when last saved correctly)
// etc........
// ...........
node: 169, 1.4, 100.0, 0,   -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1f1f1fff
node: 222, 1.0, 100.0, 100, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1f1f1fff
node: 180, 1.4, 100.0, 0,   -90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1f1f1fff

// (The file that is corrupted)
// etc........
// ...........
node: 169, 1.4, 100.0, 0,   -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1f1f1fff
node: 222, 1.0, 100.0, 100, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1f1f1fff
node: 180, 1.4, 100.0, 0,   0.0,  0.0, 2.3429216E-38, 7f7fffff
                            ^^^ why 0.0?, should be "-90.0", everything from here on is wrong...
```

What are possible reasons for a FileOutputStream to write wrong data? It's wrapped in a GZIPOutputStream.

When I write the float value to the stream I use this function:

```
public static void floatToOutputStream(float v, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(v);
    outputStream.write((bits >> 24) & 0xff);
    outputStream.write((bits >> 16) & 0xff);
    outputStream.write((bits >> 8) & 0xff);
    outputStream.write(bits & 0xff);
}
```

It apparently works, as all the other bytes of data are properly saved across this and countless other user files. So why does it seemingly randomly fail?

I noticed in Java's DataOutputStream, their function looks like this:

```
public static void floatToOutputStream(float v, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    intToOutputStream(Float.floatToIntBits(v), outputStream);
}

public static void intToOutputStream(int v, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write((v>>> 24) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write((v>>> 16) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write((v>>>  8) & 0xFF);
    outputStream.write((v>>>  0) & 0xFF);
}
```

Would that change prevent this inconsistency? What other possible causes are there? The Android environment?

Comment: you could use BufferWriter or BufferOutputStream to print correctly without any int to bits conversion troubles (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)

Comment: thanks but i'm really just looking to understand why this particular glitch is occurring